# Report on email retention labels using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My unattended ASP.NET Core (C#/Azure) task needs to use Graph API (NuGet package preferably instead of REST API directly) to report on the number of emails from all users that do and don't have a retention label linked.

Should I be checking the message properties MultiValueExtendedProperties & SingleValueExtendedProperties? If I toggle the retention label for a particular message then I can't see any differences in any message properties. I've expanded the properties.

Should I be checking the Extensions property? I get this error if I try getting the Extensions property: "Error The expression cannot be evaluated.  A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.   Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.MainError"

```
var extensions = await graphClient.Users[email].MailFolders[mailFolder.Id].Messages[message.Id].Extensions.GetAsync();
```

1. How do I accomplish my requirement?
2. Do I have to enumerate every group, then every group user, then every user mailbox folder, then every message? Or is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graph doesn't have any direct support for retention or compliance tags via the strongly typed properties (EWS had this support) so if you want to view/set them you need to use the extended properties. Extensions are more for custom application's and aren't relevant to retention. Eg to the the retention and compliacetags on message in the inbox something like

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/MailFolders/Inbox/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject&$Top=1000&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id eq 'Binary 0x3019') or (Id eq 'Integer 0x301D') or (Id eq 'Integer 0x301A') or (Id eq 'Binary 0x301B') or (Id eq 'SystemTime 0x301C') or (Id eq 'String {403FC56B-CD30-47C5-86F8-EDE9E35A022B} Name ComplianceTag') or (Id eq 'Binary 0x348A'))
```

You can find all the properties in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/55e68a31-8e6e-482f-be53-ef592b55b337?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: We're using retention labels. I don't have any say in what our company uses. I ran the query and I get a 200 response with no data. I can see that the query includes the PidTagRetention* items. What's the likely reason that the query returns no data? Also is it possible to accomplish what I want with PowerShell?

Comment: That query was targeting the dumpster I edited it so it would be the Inbox which should have messages in there give it another try. Yes you can do it with the Powershell Graph SDK, the syntax can be a little bit painful because of the way the cmdlets are autogenerated but you can always just use Invoke-MgGraphRequest if all else fails.